# Converting from SQL'ish syntax of LINQ to inline

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

First of all - please someone suggest a better name to distinguish between the inline syntax and the not-so-much-inline syntax (i.e. the SQL-ish one).   :)

I though that they were fully interchangeable and the one was a syntactic sugar for the other. However, I got this one to compile fine:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows =
  from DataRow row in table.Rows
  select row;
```

while

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> a = table.Rows.Select(...);
```

doesn't. I also tried to remake it but there's no *AsEnumerable()* in there, nor on the table holding the rows. What am I missing?!
        select row;

I also noticed that although there's *AsQueryable()* on the rows, I still can't use any of my **inline** LINQ magic on it. No *Select(...)* for instance...

Comment: those are called "query syntax" and "method syntax".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that DataRowCollection (the type that .Rows is) only implements `IEnumerable`
and not `IEnumerable<T>`.  Therefore the following syntax only works because of the word DataRow, here you are actually casting from object to DataRow

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows =
from DataRow row in table.Rows
select row;
```

If you remove the word DataRow it no longer works:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows =
from row in table.Rows
select row;
```

Which is equivilent to:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> a = table.Rows.Select(x => x);
```

So you have to cast from object to DataRow to get from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<DataRow>` so you can either do this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> a = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>();
```

Or you can use the AsEnumerable extension method on DataTable which under the covers does something similar:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> a = table.AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following one:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> a = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x=>x);
```

Comment: `Select(x=>x);` makes no sense

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes it does, if used in a general statement to make a point not related to any restriction on the original set. Which, in fact, is the exact point of this question. In real life? Well, we agree there - that'd be an eyebrows lifter.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel when you have `from x in collection select x`. Isn't equivalent to `collection.Select(x=>x)`? Actually, as I know (I might be wrong) the compiler will compile the first query the second one.

Comment: You're perfectly right, C. I think that Sriram thought of a more pragmatical aspect. While correct, your answer doesn't do anything to the original set. Which is **right spot on** in this case. +1

Comment: @Christos What you did is literal translation(rough though if you look pedantic) but you could avoid `Select(x=>x);` is my point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exists, not for `Rows` but for `Table`.

```
var rows = table.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Ar eyou sure, mate? I go *DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.As...* and intellisense gives me nada...

Comment: @KonradViltersten Please go through provided link. It exist in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` assembly. Make sure you have the reference to it.